# Microsoft SQL Parent Problem

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am rather stuck, I've had a good look around but I am not exactly sure how I can do this.

I've got to build a SP (TSQL) to bring back a navigation, but I am having a few issues with ordering the navigation correctly.

Table Example

```
NavID     OrderID     ParentID      NavName
1         1           0             Home
2         2           0             About
3         3           0             Contact Us
4         1           2             About Us Page
5         2           2             About Us Page 2
6         1           4             Another SubPage
```

All I need to bring back is the navigation above, and one navigation below.

So if I passed NavigationID 2 I would expect the results to come back like this

```
Home 
About
About Us Page 
About Us Page 2
Contact Us
```

If I passed in NavigationID 6 I would expect to see ..

```
Home
About
About Us Page
Another SubPage
About Us Page 2
Contact Us
```

As you can see it takes in account the OrderID, but make's sure the Child's are in order first.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: "So an example would be if ParentID = 2 then it would only show History, not History SubPag": what's History?  What do NavID, OrderID and ParentID mean?  Your data model could use a bit of clarification.

Comment: Hi Eamon, Sorry I changed the navigation name. So Ignore that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a complete script which does what you need (includes your test data):

```
DECLARE @nav TABLE (
            NavID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
            OrderID INT NOT NULL,
            ParentID INT,
            NavName nvarchar(MAX) NOT NULL 
        ); 
INSERT @nav 
        SELECT 1, 1, 0, 'Home' UNION ALL 
        SELECT 2, 2, 0, 'About' UNION ALL 
        SELECT 3, 3, 0, 'Contact Us' UNION ALL 
        SELECT 4, 1, 2, 'About Us Page' UNION ALL 
        SELECT 5, 2, 2, 'About Us Page 2' UNION ALL 
        SELECT 6, 1, 4, 'Another SubPage'; 

DECLARE @NavigationID int; 
SET     @NavigationID = 2;

WITH Ancestors AS (          
    SELECT @NavigationID NavID
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT  n.ParentID
    FROM    @nav n 
    JOIN Ancestors a ON (n.NavID = a.NavID)
),
VisibleNav AS (
    SELECT  n.*, CONVERT(FLOAT, 1)/SUM(1) OVER (PARTITION BY n.ParentID) Mul, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY n.ParentID ORDER BY n.OrderID)-1 Pos
    FROM @nav n 
    JOIN Ancestors a ON n.ParentID = a.NavID
),
SortedNav AS (
    SELECT vn.*, vn.Pos*vn.Mul Sort, 1 Depth
    FROM VisibleNav vn
    WHERE vn.ParentID = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT vn.NavID, vn.OrderID, vn.ParentID, vn.NavName, vn.Mul*sn.Mul, vn.Pos, vn.Pos*(vn.Mul*sn.Mul)+sn.Sort, sn.Depth + 1
    FROM VisibleNav vn
    JOIN SortedNav sn ON sn.NavID = vn.ParentID
)
SELECT sn.NavID, sn.OrderID, sn.ParentID, sn.NavName
FROM SortedNav sn
ORDER BY sn.Sort, sn.Depth;
```

Basically, I have a recursive CTE to create a list of all parents which need to be used in your navigation including the depth of the parent (so that the order is not dependent on the IDs), and then I join the navigation entries on that.

Comment: Hi Lucero, Thanks but this doesnt work. It comes back with "About Us Page" and "About Us Page 2' under "Contact Us", which is incorrect. Contact Us should be below About Us Page 2.

Comment: It should bring back the Navigation like this (If NavigationID = 2 was passed). Home, About Us, About Us Page, About Us Page 2, Contact Us.

Comment: I see, I first understood your question so that the selection of the items was the important part. The edited code now also gets the order as required.

Answer (score 0):

Common Table Expressions permit recursive queries.  However, they *can* be very slow and can seriously confuse the query optimizer, particularly if you use (and you generally should) parametrized queries.  For small tables (such as navigation) that will not participate in large joins with other (large) tables, CTE's work fine.  You can also cache the result of the common table expression in a table and rerun the caching query anytime the navigation table changes (generally not frequently, I'm guessing) - the query optimizer deals with simple many-to-many relation tables much better.

However, there are also other ways of representing tree's in SQL server. 
You could look at

- **lft/rgt style columns** whereby a ordering is defined in as the order of the lft column and a node X is a descendant of Y whenever Y.lft < X.lft < Y.rgt.  See: http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/hierarchical-data-database/2
- **HierarchyID's**.  Sql Server 2008 introduced a special data type for exactly this purpose; however updating the tree structure isn't always trivial with these.  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc794278.aspx

Finally, when I need to use CTE's I generally start with something along the lines of...

```
with nav_tree (ParentID, ChildID, depth_delta) as ( 
    SELECT basenode.NavID, basenode.NavID, 0
    FROM NavTable AS basenode
  UNION ALL
    SELECT treenode.ParentID, basenode.NavID, depth_delta+1
    FROM NavTable AS basenode 
    JOIN nav_tree AS treenode ON basenode.ParentID=treenode.ChildID
)
--select statement here joining the nav_tree with the original table and whatnot
```

Note that your exact order requirements are quite tricky; in particular where you want the children of an element to immediately be listed inline; i.e. the "About Us Page, Another SubPage, About Us Page 2" segment of your second example.  In particular, that means you cannot just order by `depth_delta` and secondarily by orderid - you'll need a path-based sort.  You might want to do this in code, rather than in sql, but you *can* construct a path in a CTE as follows:

```
with nav_tree (ParentID, ChildID, depth_delta,orderpath) as ( 
    SELECT basenode.NavID, basenode.NavID, 0, convert(varchar(MAX), basenode.OrderID)
    FROM NavTable AS basenode
  UNION ALL
    SELECT treenode.ParentID, basenode.NavID, depth_delta+1, treenode.orderpath+','+basenode.OrderID
    FROM NavTable AS basenode 
    JOIN nav_tree AS treenode ON basenode.ParentID=treenode.ChildID
)
```

...and then you can `order by` that orderpath.  Since you also want "one level below" each ancestor-or-self unfolded, you'll still need to join with NavTable to get those.

However, given your sorting requirements, **I'd recommend HierarchyIDs**: they have your sorting semantics built-in, and they also avoid the potential performance issues CTE's can expose.

Comment: I cant see another way of bringing back the structure as it is. I am open to suggestions, but really all I want to do is bring back the results like the user would see the navigation, if that makes sense.

Comment: I've got the correct SQL results pulling back, but I need to order them, does this make things a bit easier? I was thinking if I could just order the results correctly, that would save a bit of hassle?

Answer (score 0):

I'd be tempted to create a table variable, run the query for NavID <= the parent parameter where parentID = 0 and add to the table.  Then get the child items, insert to table variable and finally get the > NavID Where ParentID = 0.

A fudge but it should work.

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (NavName nvarchar(50), OrderID int)
INSERT @Table (NavName, OrderID) (SELECT NavName, OrderID FROM @Table1 WHERE (ParentID = 0) AND (NavID <= @ParentID))
INSERT @Table (NavName,OrderID) (SELECT NavName, OrderID+ 500 FROM @Table1 WHERE ParentID = @ParentID )
INSERT @Table (NavName,OrderID) (SELECT NavName, OrderID + 1000 FROM @Table1 WHERE ParentID = 0 AND NavID > @ParentID)

SELECT * FROM @Table ORDER BY OrderID
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a little unclear as to precisely which nodes you wish to display... but if I understand correctly the main question here is how to *order* the resulting nodes.  The principal difficulty is that the ordering criteria are variable length: a node must be ordered based upon the entire sequence of `OrderId` values for the node and all of its ancestors.  For example, the ordering sequence for node 6 is '2, 1, 1'.

SQL does not handle such variable-length sequences well.  I propose that we use an NVARCHAR(MAX) value for the ordering sequence.  For node 6, we will use '0002.0001.0001'.  In this form, the nodes can be ordered trivially using string comparison.  Note that the identifier values must be zero-padded in order to ensure correct ordering (I arbitrarily chose to pad to 4 digits -- the real application may require a different choice).

So this brings us to the nuts and bolts.  We'll start by creating a table called `NavigationData` to hold our test data:

```
SELECT NULL AS NavId, NULL AS OrderId, NULL AS ParentId, NULL AS NavName
  INTO NavigationData WHERE 1=0
UNION SELECT 1, 1, 0, 'Home'
UNION SELECT 2, 2, 0, 'About'
UNION SELECT 3, 3, 0, 'Contact Us'
UNION SELECT 4, 1, 2, 'About Us Page'
UNION SELECT 5, 2, 2, 'About Us Page 2'
UNION SELECT 6, 1, 4, 'Another SubPage'
```

Now, we'll create a helper view that, for every possible desired node, lists all of the related nodes along with their computed path strings.  As I said at the beginning, I feel the criteria for selecting the related nodes are underspecified, so the desired/related JOIN expression may need to be adjusted for datasets with more nodes than the simple example.  With that caveat, here is the view:

```
CREATE VIEW NavigationHierarchy AS
WITH
  hierarchy AS (
    SELECT
      NavId AS RootId
    , 1 AS Depth
    , NavId
    , RIGHT('0000' + CAST(OrderId AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 4) AS Path
    , ParentId
    , NavName
    FROM NavigationData
    WHERE ParentId = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      parent.RootId
    , parent.Depth + 1 AS Depth
    , child.NavId
    , parent.Path + '.'
      + RIGHT('0000' + CAST(child.OrderId AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 4) AS Path
    , child.ParentId
    , child.NavName
    FROM hierarchy AS parent
    INNER JOIN NavigationData AS child
      ON child.ParentId = parent.NavId
  )
SELECT
  desired.NavId AS DesiredNavId
, related.*
FROM hierarchy AS desired
INNER JOIN hierarchy AS related
  ON related.Depth <= desired.Depth + 1
  AND related.RootId IN (desired.RootId, related.RootId)
```

Most of the query is a straight-forward recursive descent of the hierarchy using a common table expression.  The heart of the solution is the generation of the `Path` columns.  Naturally, you may prefer to bake this query directly into a larger query or stored proc rather than creating a view.  The view is convenient for testing, however.

Armed with the view, we can now generate the desired results, in the requested order.  I have included the generated path in the query result for illustrative purposes.  Here is the query for node 2:

```
SELECT NavName, Path
FROM NavigationHierarchy
WHERE DesiredNavId = 2
ORDER BY Path
```

yielding:

```
Home              0001
About             0002
About Us Page     0002.0001
About Us Page 2   0002.0002
Contact Us        0003
```

and for node 6:

```
SELECT NavName, Path
FROM NavigationHierarchy
WHERE DesiredNavId = 6
ORDER BY Path
```

yielding:

```
Home              0001
About             0002
About Us Page     0002.0001
Another SubPage   0002.0001.0001
About Us Page 2   0002.0002
Contact Us        0003
```